Rigid Body Simulation rotation is not affected by forces
Rigid body simulation's rotation are not affected by forces.
For example a skinny cylinder with wind blowing on it and animation the wind randomly will only move the cylinder and it will always be facing the same direction. Even with multiple forces like turbulence or more wind.
I have gravity turned off but also tried it turned on to see and same results. The only way rotation is affected is by collisions. I have tried this with multiple objects. I have also tried animating the rotation at first and seeing if forces would work once I turned off the animation and it does not change anything the rotation will eventually stop no matter what.
Does anyone know why this is?

i don't why, i just can confirm that it is that way. Maybe you wanna file a bug report for that?

Blender doesn't have a realistic physic simulator, you need to cheat

@moonboots: whaaaat? cheat!???!?!!? what do you mean by that? Cheating hurts....!!!! i am a bit disappointed by your shameful proposal!!!!

Hey I'm french, frenchs cheat! deal with it!!! @Chris

I'm kidding of course, only italians cheat

I did eventually cheat lol. Thank you for validation that I am not crazy! :)

This does not seem to be possible for now:

Rotation

Influence the rotation of particles with Dynamic Rotation. 
The option is not relevant for other types of physics systems.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/123847

